# Class not found exception while class is added

Tags: java, android

I am doing SqlServer connectivity in Android.

I am including all the necessary jar files for it.

[image]

Buildpath Snap:

[image]

**Error Line:**

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
```

ORDER & EXPORT:

[image]

**Edit**

```
package com.example.sqlservercall;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.2.2;instance=14GRAFICALI\\MSSQLSERVER2008;databaseName=AndroidDB;integrated security=true";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView tvData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedData);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);                   

            System.out.println("connected");
            Statement statement=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from AndroidDB");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                tvData.setText(" Data1 : "+resultSet.getString(1)+"  Data 2 : "+resultSet.getNString(2));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tvData.setText(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Exception Detailed:

[image]

NEW Error afeter Checking jars in order and export:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
[2013-09-06 18:24:04 - SQLServerCall] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
[2013-09-06 18:24:23 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
[2013-09-06 18:24:23 - SQLServerCall] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ActivityCorrelator$1;
```

Comment: Is it checked under the Order and Export tab? Not sure if it might need to be in there too. Also, maybe just clean the project.

Comment: Try Project -> Clean once. Eclipse sometimes behaves wierd

Comment: no cleaning project also does not helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458788/classnotfoundexception-in-loading-jdbc-driver check this

Comment: you are not exporting the library, hence it is not in your package, hence it is not found

Comment: you should not be doing this anyway...

Comment: @njzk2 then how should i fix it? how can i export it?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu then in which way i should dop it? please sir guid me

Comment: you should not connect from android to an SQLServer... why would you want to do that?

Comment: check the checkbox corresponding to the library you wish to export in the order and export tab.

Comment: @njzk2 sir i checked it, then also same error....plz check my updated snap about it

Comment: @njzk2 sir new error after checking jars...plz see my updated error below

Comment: you probably need to use only one of these 2 libraries

Comment: yup,, sir you were right, after checking only one of it error is gone and new error is: "The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.0.2.2, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I What I assume Ovidiu means is that it is usually preferred to have your Application connect to a web interface which in turn connects to your database. So that the web interface acts as a separate layer between your database and your Application. The risks of including the connection information in your application is that your application can easily be decompiled, and thus your database connection secrets laid bare.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yup, i know it, but boss is telling me to do like this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the libraries are in "Android Private Libraries" and add "Android Private Libraries" in `Order and Export` tab.

It should be enough having the libraries inside the `libs` directory, you don't need to add them to the build path since all files in the `libs` directory is automatically added to the build path (through "Android Private Libraries").

I also believe that you are attempting to instantiate the wrong class, try with the class name **`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`** (I noticed in your screenshot that the real package name is **`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc`** and **not** `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver`)

Edit: (Updated answer after your updates)

I assume both sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar include the same classes, if that is the case you can only include one of them in your project.

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I see updated answer, I believe you are trying with the wrong classname. Through your screenshot, I can see the real package name is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc` but you switched `sqlserver` and `jdbc` in your code.

Comment: yeah its true that it was wrongly written, i changed it as u pointed out, but unfortunatly same error again

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I please update your question and add more code along with the detailed exception that you get.

Comment: @ShrimantBajiraoPeshawe-I Thanks for calling me Sir :) Updated my answer again.

Comment: sir i have done the connection sucessfully, and have mentioned the steps in the link which i provided in my answer :) Thanx For your support :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your screenshot, you should replace :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver")
```

with :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

Comment: i changed it as u pointed out, but unfortunatly same error again

Answer (score 1):

The Error is of **"Multiple Dex File"** so must be you have add Same jar multiple times as per your Screenshot see **Buildpath Snap:**  there are two **sqljdbc.ja**r. keep only one(keep latest one,remove other) then move to **ORDER & EXPORT:** and select mostly all check box. like Android support version 4 also. It will solve your issue..