# Classpath issue in connecting Java EE 7 enterprise app to SQL Server in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans-8, java-ee-7, sql-server-2014-express

Attempting to connect a Java EE7 Enterprise application to a SQL Server 2014 Express db (on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, as well as another case on Windows Server 2008 R2).  IDE is NetBeans 8.0.2. Web server is GlassFish 4.1. JDK 1.8.

The connection itself seems to work in the sense that I have created the DB in SQL Server, added a new connection under 'Services' on the Database in NetBeans, and employed sqljdbc42.jar as the Driver, with host = "localhost", port =1433, username and password set. Connection test is successful.

TCP/IP is turned on in SQL Server Config Manager.

Problem is evident when setting up JDBC Connection Pool in GlassFish . On pinging: "Ping Connection Pool failed [..] Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

The project builds, but does not deploy.

The salient server output seems to be:

```
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
Severe:   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : jdbc/assessingReports__pm
```

I note the following from BalusC in regards to classpath in NetBeans (from [classNotFoundException in Loading JDBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458788/classnotfoundexception-in-loading-jdbc-driver)):

> "Please note that the CLASSPATH environment variable is ignored by Netbeans
>   and all other decent Java programs. Forget about it and don't even try to set
>   it until you understand why it exists and what it is to be used for."

Accordingly, after initially attempting to set CLASSPATH environment in cmd like everyone else, I've been looking at how I am adding sqljdbc42.jar to the Project. I've done so via Project Properties both on the web project and the EJB module.

I have tried adding the jar both by selecting "Copy to Libraries Folder" option and alternatively by selecting "Absolute Path" option.

[image]

.. and the jar file appears to be added successfully to the libraries

[image]

I have also manually put the sqljdbc42.jar into web\WEB-INF\lib\ and then restarted NetBeans. The jar in the web-inf lib remains green.

[image]

I might be missing something generally in how to add jars (as opposed to libraries) to non-Maven NetBeans projects.

The problem persists.
Any comments or assistance appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of those *facepalm* situations.
Looks like it is only resolving by rebuilding the project from scratch on the destination platform (a Windows Server 2008 R2). Quite likely I was repeatedly stymied previously by build files that were an overhang from the platform it was initially built on, with its connection to JavaDB rather than SQL server: The old build files kept on looking for files that weren't there.
In regards to the loading of JARs in NetBeans, I can observe that the deployment is sensitive to the location from which the JAR is loaded. I am now avoiding placing the JARs in WEB-INF in the war or web module. This seems to create problems with the build, at least as far as sqljdbc42.jar or similar driver files are concerned.